# Is it "Rob's and Ron's emails are xyz@com and abc@com." or "Rob and Ron's emails are xyz@com and abc@com."?

Tags: possessives, compound-possessives

In the possessive, which is one is correct?

I am assuming that Rob and Ron's email means they both have the same email whereas, Rob's and Ron's emails are 2 distinct emails for each one.

Comment: Yes, I would assume the same. You can always add _respectively_ to make it clear.

Comment: To avoid confusion, you can rephrase as "Rob's email is xyz@com and Ron's is abc@com."

Comment: In your title, you use *emails* both times, not email. Then you list two addresses, so we can figure out not only that each has one, but which is which from the emails with Rob's name and Ron's name right there. Once you force Rob's and Ron's *emails-es*, I don't see a sleek solution without rephrasing per @WeatherVane or other formats.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.